# 'Incorrect syntax near GROUP, What does it mean when it is an incorrect syntax?

Tags: c#, sql

I am creating a form that I can add a menu item to display All Suppliers and Suppliers Quantity by Part number. So I got ReportSupplierDisplayALl to work when I ran. But When I try to run the form for the ReportSuppliersDisplayByPartnumber because When I enter the SupplierID and when I did it threw an exception.
When it throws an exception, what does it mean by incorrect syntax?

```
    public DataTable DisplaySupplierByPartNumber(string PartNumber)
    {
        // Add using System.Data

        string queryString = "SELECT Suppliers.SupplierName, Suppliers.Email, Parts.PartName, SUM(Inventory.Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity, PartNumber " +
        "FROM ((Suppliers INNER JOIN Parts ON Suppliers.SupplierID = Parts.Supplier) INNER JOIN Inventory ON Parts.PartNumber = Inventory.PartNumber " +
        "INNER JOIN Employees ON Inventory.EmpID = Employees.EmpID " +
        "GROUP BY Suppliers.SupplierName, Suppliers.Email, Parts.PartName, Parts.PartNumber " +
        "HAVING Parts.PartNumber = @PartNumber " +
        "ORDER BY Suppliers.SupplierName ";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_strCon))
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, con);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartNumber", PartNumber );
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable theTable = new DataTable();
                theTable.Load(reader);
                return theTable;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZvq7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAEFi.png)

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with C#.  The syntax error is in your *SQL* statement.  SUGGESTION: Assuming you're using MSSQL, copy/paste the statement into SQL Object Explorer (MSVS) or SSMS and refine it until you "get it right".  Start by eliminating the (bogus!) parenthesis in your statement.

Comment: You have two opening parentheses after FROM but only one closing before the GROUP BY.

Comment: Debugging is part of programmer's job.  Have you tried to print the content of your variable `queryString` before you execute it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "" For String use @ "Your Query And Make Sure You get all bracket correct"
also change element  take  part number first then use your aggerate function

```
string queryString = @"SELECT S.SupplierName, S.Email, P.PartName, SUM(Inventory. Quantity) AS SumOfQuantity FROM Suppliers as s
INNER JOIN Parts as p on P.SupplierId=P.SupplierId
INNER JOIN Inventory ON Parts.PartNumber = Inventory.PartNumber 
INNER JOIN Employees ON Inventory.EmpID = Employees.EmpID 
GROUP BY S.SupplierName, S.Email, P.PartName, P.PartNumber 
HAVING Parts.PartNumber = @PartNumber
ORDER BY S.SupplierName"
```

Comment: The OP's original SQL has several problems.  It's unclear exactly what he's trying to do ... but your suggested queryString looks good!